# Route constraint to check if Url contains any controller name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to create a route which does not belong to any controller. Means if url does not contain any controller name it should redirect to a particular action

How can I create constraint for such route.

For example if I have route such as

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "user",
            url: "{username}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home",     action="username",id=UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { isuser = new checkuserConstraint() }
        );
```

what should be constraint so that it wont redirect to default `home/index` route

EDIT:  If use `www.domain.com/admin/adminid` as url it will return error as there is no controller named admin..in this case I want it to call the `username` action of `home` controller.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Please say exactly what you want? Provide some URL and matched action.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want map a url such as `/admin/1` to the `AccountController.DoSomething(int id, string username)`, for example, first you need to add following route rule with a custom constraint to filter out unmatched username, before your default rule.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myRoute",
    url: "{username}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "DoSomething" },
    constraints: new { username = new MyCatConstraint() }
);
 // your other route rules are here
```

Your custom constraint could be something like this:

```
public class MyCatConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    // suppose this is your username list. In the real world a DB provider 
    private string[] _myUsernames = new[] { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        // return true if you found a match on your user's list otherwise false
        // in the real world you could query from DB to match cats instead of searching from the array.  
        if(values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            return _myUsernames.Any(c => c == values[parameterName].ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This route matches with following action:

```
public AccountController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething(int id, string username)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: admin is username. for different uers it will be different

Comment: What is `adminid` then? Your url could be `/admin/1` or `/user1/2` or  `/user2/2` and you want map all of them to a single action?

Comment: Finally we understand each other. ;) I have updated the post to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks..This is what I wanted :)